# Regular Expression not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to C# so please don't mind some basic mistakes.
I am trying to search a pattern of 2 characters and about 4 numbers in strings. 
In first case it finds the string "UM2345678", but when I have same in longer string, it does not find the same string "UM2345678". Any idea?

Also, if I want to search for particulary UM and any 4 numbers then what will be the pattern?

Thanks.

```
 namespace StringSearch
 {
class TestRegularExpressionValidation
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] numbers = 
    {
        "123-555-0190", 
        "444-234-22450", 
        "690-555-0178", 
        "146-893-232",
        "146-555-0122",
        "4007-555-0111", 
        "407-55-0111",
        "a1b-Cd-EfgH",
        "a1b-Cd-Efgn",
        "UM2345678",
        "11/12/2013 4:10:06 PM                                 UM2345678",
        "407-2-5555", 
    };
        string sPattern = "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}";


        foreach (string s in numbers)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0,14}", s);
            Match m = Regex.Match(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");
            }


        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to search a pattern of 2 characters and about 4 numbers in
>   strings. In first case it finds the string "UM2345678", but when I
>   have same in longer string, it does not find the same string
>   "UM2345678". Any idea?

Remove the "^".It means the following pattern is at the beginning of the string.

```
string sPattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4,}";
```

> Also, if I want to search for particulary UM and any 4 numbers then
>   what will be the pattern?

Try this:

```
string sPattern = @"UM\d{4}";
```

Comment: are we not supposed to start the search from the begining of the line?

Comment: yes, but I mean the "^" matches the starting position within the string,in other words, pattern "^UM" means .StartWith("UM") while pattern "UM" means .Cotains("UM"), and FYI, pattern "UM$" means .EndsWith("UM").@user2026794

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the line you refer to as a "longer string" is this one:
"11/12/2013 4:10:06 PM                                 UM2345678"

The reason your regex isn't matching it, is because of the '^' character.  That is a meta character that says "start matching at the beginning of a line".  If you remove that from your regex, then it should match the above string.

As for your second question, change the [a-zA-Z] to just be UM.

A helpful tool for testing regexes in .NET is Expresso, found [here](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm)

Comment: It worked by removing ^, but are we not supposed to start the search from the begining of the line?  Also when I change it to "UM[0-9]{4}" and then change the data string to "UN2345678" it still finds it. I only want it to find when it is UM. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer slightly.  The ^ character starts matching at the start of the line.  If your specific text is not always going to be at the start, then you should not be trying to match the start.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for any input (locates 2 letters followed by 4 digits):

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}
```

And this for your special case:

```
UM\d{4}
```

Comment: Getting ~ error on \d when using: string sPattern = "[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}"  or string sPattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}";

Comment: Use a double \\ or prefix your string with an @, i.e. "[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{4}" or @"[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}"

Answer (score 0):

You regex pattern has a ^ in the beginning which means that you are looking for the pattern from the start of the string. Try changing your pattern as follows...

```
[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4,}
```

That means 4 or more numbers.